# Corda settler Exception during node startup when running runnodes command

Tags: blockchain, corda, ripple

I am trying to run runnodes command inside nodes folder after successful execution of deployNodes command. Four Nodes are getting invoked- Notary, PartyA, partyB, Oracle. Notary nodes is in working state but in PartyA, PartyB, Oracle nodes I am getting below mentioned error:-

[ERROR] 15:19:15+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Attempting to register over an existing platform flow: class net.corda.confidential.SwapIdentitiesFlow [errorCode=aixp30, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/5.0-SNAPSHOT/aixp30]

I am working on Windows. Thanks!

The corda settler I am running is the one developed by Roger Willis and can be found at https://github.com/corda/corda-settler

Comment: have any node started? if it's have ,try to re-start the problem node again

Comment: Yes, all the nodes started after the runnodes command but only Notary nodes were able to remain as the working nodes. The rest all encountered the exception above and the terminal automatically closes.

Comment: you can restart only notary node by go to the notary terminal and use last command

Comment: What do you mean by going to Notary node (the only node that remains running) and run last command?? My last command was runnodes

Comment: I mean go to node terminal that die and run the command for start
bash -c 'cd "path/to/your/node/A" ; "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" "-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=port=7006,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4jAdapter" "-Dname=PartyA" "-jar" "/path/to/your/node/A/corda.jar" && exit'

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. Only the Notary node is working fine. The other three nodes has errors in the console. Seems something has been updated during the last couple of weeks. The work around could be to roll back to a stable version couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I have tried with the commit from 20th March and it is working. There is already reported an issue with the detailed description. I guess that corda team will fix it very soon.